# xpath selection based by nodeName

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an XML Like the following, and i want select just the elements "b" and "c" childrens of "a" using xpath filtering in xslt

```
<a>
  <b>data_1</b>
  <c>data_1</c>
  <d>data_1</d>
  <e>data_1</d>
</a>
<a>
  <b>data_2</b>
  <c>data_2</c>
  <d>data_2</d>
  <e>data_2</d>
</a>
<a>
  <b>data_3</b>
  <c>data_3</c>
  <d>data_3</d>
  <e>data_3</d>
</a>
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First, do notice that you haven't provided a well-formed XML document**. By definition a well-formed XML document must have a single top element.

**I assume in this answer, that all `a` elements are children of this single top element, that isn't shown in the question.**

---

**Use**:

```
/*/a/*[self::b or self::c]
```

This selects any element that is either `b` or `c` and that is a child of any `a`element that is a child of the top element of the XML document.

Do note that the currently-accepted answer is incorrect:

```
/a/*[self::a or self::b or self::c]
```

Not only it supposes that there is a single `a` top element (and there isn't such), but given a specific XML document, it would select, besides the wanted elements, also any `a` element that is a child of the top element `a`.

The XPath expression that I recommend above:

```
/*/a/*[self::b or self::c]
```

is more efficient than another, correct XPath expression that is proposed in one of the other answers:

```
/a/b | /a/c
```

This requires evaluatiing separately `/a/b/` and `/a/c` and then performing the set-union of the results of the two evaluations.

The XPath expression that I recommend needs only a single scan of the document, requires no union and can be used even in streaming mode over an unlimited in size, huge XML document.

Comment: for XPATH 2.0, is /*/a/*[self::b or self::c] better than /*/a/(b|c) ? Also which predicate is better [self::b or self::c]? or [self::b | self::c]?

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin: I believe that both alternatives should be equally efficient. `self::b or self::c` is more straightforward and doesn't require conversion from a node-set to a boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

In XPATH 2.0+, the simplest expression to select b & c is ...

```
/a/(b|c)
```

Note that in XPATH 2.0, if you don't need nodes to be sorted in document order, you could also use ...

```
/a/(b,c)
```

In XPATH 1.0, you will need ...

```
/a/b | /a/c
```